# Add target line to pivot chart

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table, excel-2016

I am stuck with trying to add a target line to my pivot chart.
Here's what the pivot table and chart look like:

[image: Pivot table and chart]

My table has a column with target numbers, I figured I add this and right click that bar and change it to a line chart. However adding this to the pivot table will result in three extra bars per Role because Each Manager column will get this column added. How do I get around this?

Comment: Is the target the same for each manager?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Yes the target is the same for each manager, it differs for each Role